# Multiple file upload in Sails.js with sails-hook-uploads from Vue.js: ETIMEOUT

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file-upload, sails.js, multiple-file-upload

I am trying to upload mutliple files via patch from my Vue frontend to my Sails backend. For each product there could be a single thumbnail and multiple detail images. For the request from Vue I set up a FormData Object, which includes the images (1 thumbnail, n detail images)

```
function buildMultipartFormDataObject(data) {
  let formData = new FormData()
  //append text before images
  if(data.thumbnail) formData.append('thumbnail', data.thumbnail)
  if(data.images) {
    for(let i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
      formData.append(`images[${ i }]`, data.images[i])
    }
  }
  return formData
}
```

In my sails Controller I am doing the following for uploading the files

```
module.exports = async function update (req, res) {
  // ...
  let productImagesDirname = require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images/products/')

  //uploadOne() and upload() are from 'sails-hook-uploads'
  let uploadedThumbnail = await sails.uploadOne(req.file('thumbnail'), { dirname: productImagesDirname })
  let uploadedImages = await sails.upload(req.file('images'), { dirname: productImagesDirname })
```

My thumbnail is uploading as expected but for the images I get

> Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`images[0]`) timed out before it was
>   plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You
>   can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.

for each image (image[0] ... image[n]) and right after

> Error: ETIMEOUT: An Upstream (`images`) timed out waiting for file(s).
>   No files were sent after waiting 10000ms.

even if I only want to upload the images (commented out thumbnail upload in sails&vue). So obviously sails is missing `images` in the Uploadstream?

The `_files` field of the `req.file('thumbnail')` Upstream contains a stream object

```
debug: Upstream {
  _fatalErrors: [],
  _files: [ { stream: [Object], status: 'bufferingOrWriting' } ],
```

The `_files` field of the `req.file('images')` Upstream is empty but I do not get why

```
debug: Upstream {
  _fatalErrors: [],
  _files: [],
```

Any ideas out there?

Comment: I think you can just call `formData.append('images', data.images[i])` from the front end as many times as you need to add images.

Comment: I have done that, as you can see in the first code snippet of my post. I already solved this problem but I can't remember what the problem was ‍♂️

Comment: Just use `formData.append('images', ...)` as many times as you need without the index and Sails will give you an array. There's some comments about it on the [FormData.append MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example), but ignore the bits about PHP - you _don't_ need the square braces.